# Deploying Rails app to 1&1 Virtual Server L Windows

Tags: ruby-on-rails, deployment, windows-server-2008

Evening all,

I have a rails app that I need to deploy to a 1&1 Virtual Server L Windows.

My setup uses a MYSQL db, rails 3.2, ruby 1.9 and was built on a mac.

I have read numerous accounts of Linux style deployments, however do the same rules apply when using a windows server? Some articles reccomend ftp'ing your app and then installing 3 other dependencies. Is this too good to be true?

I realise this is a fairly open ended question, but does anyone know the first few steps to getting this thing up and running or any helpful documents?

Thanks in Advance

Andy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't tested it, because I'm not using a windows server, but have you checked this?
https://github.com/SciMed/capistrano-windows-server

Comment: Seems like they have made some proper headway with windows deployment, although we went with linux thankfully lol.